# using viewport units in list items correctly

Tags: html, css

I try to skip chrome page zoom and prevent the effect of page zoom on elements position on the page.

So I've used viewport units successfully like this:(you can only see the results on CodePen!)

https://codepen.io/pixy-dixy/pen/abzdqjQ

The problem is for some confusing reason the same approach doesn't work for list items (ul tags)

Here is the example: (if you zoom the page in and out the list moves up and down or forward and backward):

https://codepen.io/pixy-dixy/pen/rNaxJQr

Please Note: I want the viewport units.

Here is the above code in one place but you can not test the zooming effect here.

```css
.containerText{
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 1vw;
  top: 3vh;
  height: 40vh;
  width: 19vw;   
  outline: 0.1vw dashed orange;
}

#text{
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 3vw;
  transform: scale(0.5, 0.5); 
  width: 37vw;
  height:130vh;
  opacity: 1;
  top: -24vh;
  left:-9vw;

}
.containerList {
  position: absolute; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  top: 3vh;
  left:20vw;
  width: 40vw;
  height: 40vh;
  outline: 0.1vw dashed orange;
}

ul#list{
  position: absolute;  
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 2vw;
  top:2vh;
  left:0vw;
  color: #b3a2c7;       
}
```

```html
<div class="containerText">
<span id="text">Zoom has no effect on me</span>
</div>

<div class="containerList">
<ul id="list">

  <li>
  <span class="one">First Item</span>
  </li>

  <li>
  <span class="two">Second Item</span>
  </li>  
</ul>
</div>
```

Update:

I found a solution but it dosn't seem good: (long lines of codes)

HTML:

```
<div class="containerList">
<ul class="left">

    <li>
        <span id="lefttList1">Correct</span>
    </li>

    <li>
        <span id="lefttList2">Attempts</span>
    </li>

    <li>

</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.left{
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 1.7vw;
  color: #b3a2c7; 
}

#lefttList1{
   position: absolute;
   top: 1vh;
   left:1vw;
}
```

Comment: You know that some people need that zooming to actually use your website? Why are you trying to fight something that users expect to be able to do?

Comment: @somethinghere is right, this is definitely not a good practice. I answered because it's good to learn the reason for the behavior, but I wouldn't recommend using any of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fail to see why you would want that, but the reason for that behavior is that you are not overwriting the default margins on the list, which is not set in viewport units. Just add something like:

```css
  padding-left: 10vw;
  margin-top: 6vh;
  margin-bottom: 6vh;
```

to the ul.